# Bind9 - dig example.com not showing the private IP address

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I have installed Ubuntu 20 and installed the bind9.
'DNS : ns1.example.com'
'IP: 10.201.1.253'
Created a zone files

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com. systemadmin.example.com. (
                  4     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; define Name Server
    IN  NS      ns1.example.com.
; define Name Server's IP address
    IN  A       10.201.1.253
; define each IP address of a hostname
ns1 IN  A   10.201.1.253
```

Reverse zone

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.example.com.  systemadmin.example.com. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; define Name Server
        IN  NS      ns1.example.com.

; define each hostname of an IP address2
253      IN  PTR     ns1.example.com.
```

named.conf.options

```
        allow-query { localhost; internal-network; };
       
        allow-transfer { localhost; };
     
        recursion yes;
```

Added the DNS address in netplan.
restarted the bind.
When trying to dig ns1.example.com
[image]

named.conf.local
[image]

why is it going for some external IP address? what did I do wrong here? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: did you add the authoritative zone definition in named.conf.local?  simply creating the zones without configuring the zones in BIND can lead to this.

Comment: @ThomasWard I added the zones in the conf.local, but still does not take the internal ip address